# Python / Jupyter notebook not highlighting f-strings properly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, syntax-highlighting

Below is an example of Jupyter Notebook and 2 Python code snippets:

[image]

In Jupyter it does not highlight f-strings most of the time, only if its a single variable, even when it's defined and used as `a+b` it is not highlighted.

In Python, if a variable is defined it highlights the variable but not if its with any math operations, it's just inconsistent.

I tried checking my `settings.json` but don't think the problem lies in it:

```
{
  "gitlens.advanced.messages": {
    "suppressShowKeyBindingsNotice": true
  },
  "workbench.iconTheme": "Monokai Pro (Filter Spectrum) Icons",
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.rulers": [110],
  "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
  "workbench.statusBar.visible": true,
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
  "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
  "python.pythonPath": "/opt/anaconda3/envs/abc/bin/python",
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorRuler.foreground": "#e1b525"
},
"python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
  "editor.wordWrapColumn": 200,
  "python.formatting.provider": "black",
  "launch": {
    "configurations": [],
    "compounds": []
  },
  "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
  "python.linting.mypyEnabled": true,
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
  "python.linting.enabled": false,
  "html.format.enable": false,
  "javascript.format.enable": false,
  "typescript.format.enable": false,
  "json.format.enable": false,
  "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
  "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
"kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
"jupyter.askForKernelRestart": false,
"jupyter.textOutputLimit": 0,
"jupyter.alwaysTrustNotebooks": true,
"jupyter.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": true,
"workbench.editorAssociations": {
  "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb"
},
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/opt/anaconda3/envs/abc/bin/python",
"[python]": {

  "gitlens.codeLens.symbolScopes": [
    "!Module"
  ],
  "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
}
}
```

Maybe this part `"python.formatting.provider": "black"` could do a difference but as I understand its just formatting, not highlighting.

---

###### Update

> My version of Notebook is 6.4.4 but I still have that bad highlight problem.

**Update**
Adding a screenshot of a different theme and my `.json` settings.
[image]

Comment: Hi Jonas, How are you doing? Have your problem got solved? It seems no one else has tried to help you. I actually spent some time to help you. I'll be so delighted if you vote my answer  or even choose it as the correct one ✅. Thank you in advance. 

Answer (score 0):

**Upgrade the version of notebook**
This Github link (below) shows that you may need to upgrade your notebook version to 4.4.1 or 5.0 and even higher.
[F-string Highlight Problem](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2358)

---

- **Upgrade Commands**

Use this command to upgrade: `pip install notebook --upgrade`

> Note: Anaconda users may prefer `conda update notebook`

---

**Jupyter Notebook outside of VS-Code**
I tried with my Jupyter notebook and worked fine.
[image]

This is how the Jupyter notebook looks like

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 1,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "Hello Behdad Moghadam! :)\n"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "behdad = \"Behdad Moghadam\"\n",
    "print(f\"Hello {behdad}! :)\")"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.7.6"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 4
}
```

---

**Jupyter Notbook in VS-Code**

I use this extention for Jupyter Notebook in VS-Code

[Jupyter Notebook VS-code extension marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter)

[image]

- **Result**
  It works fine for me.
  [image]

---

**Unistall and Re-install the Jupyter Notebook**

This will reset the settings and configuration to normal state.

Comment: My version is `6.4.4` but I still have that bad highlight problem.

Comment: It looks like you are using conda distributed version of the jupyter notebook, while I am using the vscode extension for it.

Comment: No, I'm not using conda, I just made the note book via this command in `cmd`: `jupyter notebook`

Comment: I added the Jupyter Notebook extension for VS-code. I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Hi @JonasPalačionis, I've updated my answer, do you mind to take a look and see if it works or not?

Comment: Hi, I checked, it does not help.

Comment: What is the problem? Can you describe the problem more?

Answer (score 0):

It can output the right results of the python file and the jupyter notebook?

Have you tried to switch the color theme?

It looks more like a Language Server problem. Can you check your editor to verify it can analyze the code correctly like this?

[image]

In the `Command Palette` -> `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`

You should find the `meta.fstring.python` after every character of the `f"{a+5} test test`.

[image]

Comment: For me it says `string.quoted.single.python` and not `meta.fstring.python`, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Jonas Palačionis Can you have a look at OUTPUT -> Python Language Server?

Comment: @Jonas Palačionis Have you installed the python extension and the pylance extension?

Comment: I have both pylance and python extentions, where do I find the output -> python language server setting?

Comment: @Jonas Palačionis It is next to `Debug Console` and `Terminal`.

Comment: For some reason I have 2 `Python Language Server` options in the dropdown, the first one is empty, the second one prints `[Info  - 10:51:20 AM] Pylance language server 2021.10.3 (pyright 2cf9c059) starting
[Info  - 10:51:20 AM] Server root directory: /Users/jonas/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.10.3/dist
`

Comment: @Jonas Palačionis Could you try to switch the color theme and attach the screenshot?

Comment: @Jonas Palačionis Sorry, could you provide a picture alike the second one in my answer and choose the Dark+ color theme?

Comment: Now the developer tokens does not open anyhting and does not show any information..

Comment: @Jonas Palačionis It's weird, even if it just was a `txt` file, it should also work.